# Help with this puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Here is a set of problems that I encountered during an examination. Can anybody help me find the numbers where the '??' symbols are?

1. $\begin{bmatrix}10&6&2\\15&31&?? \\15&96&7 \end{bmatrix}$
2. $\begin{bmatrix}??&6&3\\22&27&43 \\27&108&29 \end{bmatrix}$
3. $\begin{bmatrix}36&??&45\\126&12&61 \\45&47&6 \end{bmatrix}$
4. $\begin{bmatrix}5&39&39\\41&10&34 \\120&??&30\end{bmatrix}$

I have no clue how to solve this, can anybody help?

Comment: what replaces the question marks to make the determinate of these matrices equal to 1?

Comment: it is the place where we need to fit suitable number

Comment: What kind of exam? Linear algebra?

Comment: its basic qualification is 10th

Comment: Can we assume that each matrix is a separate problem?

Comment: Yes of course .. But i suspect they all have a common pattern..

Comment: If this is math problem then why it is here?

Comment: It is not math problem it is a puzzle but somehow it it related to math

Comment: Was it a math examination?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry How did you pick 1.  Did you solve it?

Comment: @Paparazzi It is for students upto 10th stranded

Comment: @TheHalfBloodPrince "Students upto 10th stranded" makes no sense to me

Comment: @Paparazzi It is a Question from USS examination ... I am a graduate student But I cant solve it ..

Comment: 'Students upto 10th stranded' means that competition was for students upto 10th.

Comment: I don't know what USS is and why 10th is graduate school.

Comment: Blaaahhh... It is a puzzle problem as i mentioned .. it has nothing to do with determinant and all... It is like identifying the pattern and adjoin the suitable one...I dont know further ...!! There is nothing to make much noise here

Comment: There is no "puzzle" section on the USS exams.  Even the reasoning problems require math to solve.  If you don't know 'further' then how do you know what the right answer would ever be?

Comment: @Drt USS examination is for Kerala students (In INDIA) you can check it here, Here is the link... http://103.251.43.156/lss_uss/    and I said 'I dont know further' means I dont wanna explain about it further.. Here people are making noises about examination not about Question

Answer (score 1):

If this is an example of problems given on a USS exam in some part of Asia to identify gifted students then the object is probably to test them to see if they can figure the number to place where the ?? is to cause the

> smallest value for the determinant of the given matrix.

If that is the case then the value for ?? in the first matrix is

> 4

and the value for ?? in the second matrix is

> 2

Comment: ^vote with a note: Could use more explanation, including the fact that these numbers are rounded off.